# How to add tabbar in doinbackground asynctask in android

Tags: android

How to add tabbar in doinbackground asynctask  in android? or how to run splash screen in thread? I want to show a progress dialog or splash screen until tab bar is loaded from calling tabbar class I am calling webservices and parsing the value takes time, for few mins mean time, I have to show progessbar or splash screen. Can anybody tell me how to implement this? Can anybody give sample code?
I tried but its not working

```
dlg = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Downloading Data...", true, false);    

 Thread splashThread = new Thread() { 
        @Override
        public void run() { 
           try { 

                sleep(100000); 



           } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
              // do nothing 
           } finally { 

           } 
        } 
     }; 
     splashThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot touch anything of the main ui thread from a background thread, in order to do that you have to use a handler who manages the synchronization between background thread and ui main thread.

the better way is subclassing the AsyncTask, doing this, you already have methods who works on background and methods who work on the ui. With this, you can perform the background operation and inmediatly shows the result...

```
public class AsynchronousTask extends AsyncTask<Runnable, String, Result> {

//method executed automatically in the ui event before the background thread execution
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //show the splash screen and add a progress bar indeterminate
    }

//method executed automatically in the ui event AFTER the background thread execution
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        //hide the splash screen and drop the progress bar or set its visibility to gone.
    }

//method executed in a background event when you call explicitly execute...
@Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Runnable... tasks) {
Result result;
        if(tasks != null && tasks.length > 0){
            for (Runnable runnable : tasks) {
                //publishProgress( ... );
                runnable.run();
                                //result = ...
                //publishProgress( ...);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

read more here
hope this helps...

Comment: what is the return type i will give give example

Comment: inside of the methods onPreExecute and onPostExecute you must shows an AlertDialog, refresh your splash screen, etc... because those methods run in the event thread, if you override the onProgressUpdate(int progress) you can show a ProgressBar with the progress update. this last also run in the ui.